# Convert Portrait to Landscape with Paperclip/Rails, and left-right padding to new image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip and Rails. Currently, if a user uploads a portrait image, Paperclip crops off the top and bottom of the image, and "forces" the middle section to fit my defined styles (provided below).

What I want, however, is the portrait image to be preserved, and add "spacing" to the left and right of the image. Basically, preserving the portrait image inside of a new landscape image. So far I can only find examples of simply rotating images. See examples below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's my styles info:

```
has_attached_file :image,
                  :styles => { thumb: "100x100#",
                               medium: "300x300>",
                               display: "759x506#" }
```

I currently don't have any pre/post processors or interpolations applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the ImageMagick docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#extent) you can acheive this with the `-extent` option, for example:

```
convert input.jpg -resize 800x600 -background black -compose Copy \ 
-gravity center -extent 800x600 -quality 92 output.
```

[According to the Paperclip docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/ClassMethods), you could now add the relevant command line flags to paperclip the following way. For example, for `:medium`:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { thumb: "100x100#",
                                       medium: "300x300>",
                                       display: "759x506#" },
                          :convert_options => { all: "-background black -compose Copy -gravity center"
                                                medium:  "-extent 300x300"}
```